# Google places API Autocomplete restrict to business names only

Tags: google-places-api, street-address, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google autocomplete API in a react app. By default, the user can enter a street address or the name of a business in the autocomplete search field and google will autocomplete it. How can I restrict the autocomplete field to only autocomplete business names?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the type as `establishment`.
Here is an example code:

```
  let autocomplete;
  function initMap() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
      {
        types: ["establishment"],
        componentRestrictions: { country: ["US"] },
        fields: ["place_id", "geometry", "name", "formatted_address"],
      }
    );
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", onPlaceChanged);
  }

  function onPlaceChanged() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      document.getElementById("autocomplete").placeholder = "Enter a place";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("business-name").innerHTML = place.name;
      document.getElementById("full-address").innerHTML =
        place.formatted_address;
    }
  }
```

For more info you can check [the doc here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#:%7E:text=fully%20specified%20address.-,establishment,-instructs%20the%20Place)